# ERROR: tensorflow_cpu-2.11.0-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to install tensorflow,
at beginning I thought the error was caused by `python 3.11`
I changed the interpreter to `python 3.10` but I still have the same problem.

I can't install tensorflow and the error is

```
ERROR: tensorflow_cpu-2.11.0-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl -
is not a supported wheel on this platform.'''
```

intel laptop running on `win 11`, amd `ryzen 5000 series`, amd radeon graphics

thanks

[screen vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXuMt.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The API you are using basically a single version of tensorflow `2.11.0`. Developers designed different [wheels](https://realpython.com/python-wheels/) for differnt OS requiremnts. As as the latest version of [tensorflow is 2.11.0](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/) so don't wory installing through Above API. Install directly using PIP. Let PIP decide supported version.

```
pip install tensorflow
```

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for your answer. Unfortunately I already tried this variant and it doesnt work. My doubt still related on the incompatibility between python 11 and tensorflow but I installend the 10 version and changed the interpreter.